# Is there any easy selector in JavaScript to get DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, element, inspector

I'm looking something similar to element inspector with mouse click in Opera Dragonfly and Firebug.

After my click it'll show how can I get that element in JavaScript? Is there any tool for this?

Comment: You want to click an element and have a CSS selector returned to show how to target that particular element? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think he wants a reference to the dom object to manipulate it

Comment: @Tobias: then it's even more ambiguous than I first thought...

Comment: @DavidThomas - I believe what they want a tool that can be used in-page that's similar to the *Inspect Element* tool. The in-page part is my guess, btw.

Comment: yes, then my code should be right.

Comment: I'll try to explain more;
In Dragonfly when you click an element on page; http://prntscr.com/hwv26
If an element ID I can easily get that with document.getElementByID. But If it has no ID it's a bit hard to get. I want to an easy tool to manipulate DOM.

Comment: So you're looking for something that when you click on it, it will generate a custom selector for you based on the page? For what usage, designing or coding the styles on a page? Why isn't Chrome Console, Firebug, or Dragonfly sufficient? Note also that Firefox (not Firebug) has `Inspect Q`, which I think does something like what you want. That may be what you want.

Comment: I will use it an Opera Extension to remove some elements in spesific page. Also I couldn't able to use Inspect Q? How can I run it?

Comment: It's actually part of the Web Developer "setup" that comes with Firefox nowadays (`ctrl+shift+I` to open it, if you have it). I would look to see if you can find the source code, although @TobiasSpringer's answer seems to be something like what you're looking for as a starting-off point.

Comment: but may I ask for what you need this? Almost  every browser has its own inspecting tools, no need for this ..

Comment: Here's a screen-capture: http://imgur.com/qfaqU

Answer (score 3):

Should do it:

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

Complete Code:

```
window.onmousemove=function(e) {
elem=document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
elem.style.backgroundColor="#3399ff";
}
```

Of course this is just an example and not perfect.